# Best way to handle passing of Control.Checked state between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It's been a while since I've worked with Windows Forms applications. I have a Checkbox on the Main form and, based upon a certain condition, if the Second form needs to be opened to request additional data from the user, how should I pass (or get) back a message to the Main form from the Second form so I can tell whether or not it's okay to Check or Uncheck the Checkbox?

From what I can remember, I could use something like Pass by `ref`. Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well your situation, but I don't think passing by ref is the solution here. What form is opened first? Is one form the parent of the other? When do you want to pass the value?

Comment: Did you check [those](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+pass+data+between+form)?

Comment: You probably want to look at the Form.ShowDialog method (see the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Munchies Thank you but my problem is not how to show a dialog.

Comment: Add a property to the second form and check it on the instance of the form you call showdialog on.

Comment: @Otiel: My main form is the Parent window. When a user clicks the checkbox in it, the main form will open a child dialog to request information, once the information has been entered, the child window will close and pass back a message (String) to the Main (Parent) form so the main form will know how to proceed with the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use an event.

In your child form, declare an event to be raised upon specific user interaction, and simply "subscribe" to this event in your main form.

When you instantiate and call you child form, you'd do like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.MyEvent += frm_MyEvent;
    frm.ShowDialog();
    frm.MyEvent -= frm_MyEvent;
}

private void frm_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "whatever"; //just for demo purposes
}
```

In your child form, you declare the event and raise it:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyEvent!= null)
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks!

Comment: @James: note that in my example, I used EventArgs.Empty, but you could use a "real" EventArg with values to pass back to your main form.

Comment: What would be the point of doing all of this?  The point of an event is to allow some code to be executed at an indeterminate point in the future (from the point of view of the subscriber) but the subscriber knows when it needs to execute the code.  This is essentially the model that you would need to follow if you used a *non*-modal dialog, but with a modal dialog it's just needless effort.

Comment: My solution can be applied to a wider variety of problems, not just the one where you need to read a value back from a modal dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are showing the child form as a dialog, and the parent form doesn't need it until the form as closed, all you need to do is add a property with a public getter and private setter to the child form, set the value in the child form whenever it's appropriate, and then read the value from the main form after the call to `ShowDialog`.