# Passing values between forms; Refining

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, variables, radio-button

Basically; Form1 has 2 buttons, Form2 has 1 button.
When you click Form2's button it checks which button on Form1 you clicked, opening Form3 or Form4 depending on which button you clicked (on Form1).

---

So I've utilized Mark Halls first method of passing variables between forms. Now for the second half of my closed refinement.

Form1

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Call function while storing variable info.
            Account("login");
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Call function while storing variable info.
            Account("register");
        }

        // Function used to pass Variable info to Account form while opening it as instance.
        private void Account(string formtype)
        {
            // Generate/Name new instant of form.
            frontend_account frmAcc = new frontend_account();
            // Pass variable to instance.
            frmAcc.CheckButtonClick = formtype;
            // Show form instance.
            frmAcc.Show(this);
            // Hide this instance.
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Form2

```
// String Variable to store value from Login.
        public string CheckButtonClick { get; set; }

        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If statement to open either Main form or Registration form, based on Login variable.
            if (CheckButtonClick == "login")
            {
                // Generate/Name new instant of form.
                frontend_main frmMain = new frontend_main();
                // Show form instant.
                frmMain.Show();
                // Close this instant.
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (CheckButtonClick == "register")
            {
                // Generate/Name new instant of form.
                frontend_register frmReg = new frontend_register();
                //  Show form instant.
                frmReg.Show();
                // Close this instant.
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

On Form2 there are **TWO** radio buttons, can I adept that code to set the focus of a tab control when a form is opened? ie. if radClient is checked set focus on tabcontrol after opening winform, else if radStudent is checked set focus on tabcontrol (other page) after opening winform... and i guess don't open a winform if no radio is checked.

I believe this will set the focus;

```
// Sets focus to first tab.
tabRegister.SelectedTab = tabRegister.TabPages[0];
// Sets focus to second tab.
tabRegister.SelectedTab = tabRegister.TabPages[1];
```

Comment: Look at this post for a way to pass messages between forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976205/best-way-to-handle-passing-of-control-checked-state-between-forms/12977226#12977226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the first problem I see is you are closing your parent form which closes your Form1 and disposes of Your Form2, What I would do is Hide Form1 instead of Closing it, I would then create a public property on Form2 to pass in the Button that was selected. But anytime you are opening and closing multiple Forms it can get messy, what I would do would be to create UserControls for your additional Forms and swap them out in a Panel. The first example is how to do it the way that you asked.

**Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowForm2("login");
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowForm2("register");
    } 


    private void ShowForm2(string formtype)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // Instantiate a Form2 object.
        f2.CheckButtonClick = formtype;
        f2.Show(this); // Show Form2 and  
        this.Hide(); // closes the Form1 instance.  

    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
ublic partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string CheckButtonClick { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckButtonClick == "login")
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3(); // Instantiate a Form3 object.  
            f3.Show(); // Show Form3 and  
            this.Close(); // closes the Form2 instance.  
        }
        else if (CheckButtonClick == "register")
        {
            Form4 f4 = new Form4(); // Instantiate a Form4 object.  
            f4.Show(); // Show Form4 and  
            this.Close(); // closes the Form2 instance.  
        } 

    }
}
```

**Form3 and Form4** note since Form1 is long forgotten to these forms I search for it to Open back up

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormCollection frms = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form f in frms)
        {
            if (f.Name == "Form1")
            {
                f.Show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second Option with UserControls has one Form with a Panel on it. It uses events to signal the Form to Change Controls plus a public property on UserControl2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string logonType;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void userControl1_LoginOrRegisterEvent(object sender, LoginOrRegisterArgs e)
    {
        logonType = e.Value;
        userControl2.BringToFront();
    }


    private void userControl2_ControlFinshedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logonType == "logon")
            userControl3.BringToFront();
        else if (logonType == "register")
            userControl4.BringToFront();
    }

    private void userControl3_ControlFinshedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl1.BringToFront();
    }

    private void userControl4_ControlFinshedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl1.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

**UserControl1**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
   public delegate void LoginOrRegisterHandler(object sender, LoginOrRegisterArgs e);
   public event LoginOrRegisterHandler LoginOrRegisterEvent;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginOrRegisterArgs ea = new LoginOrRegisterArgs("logon");
        LoginOrRegisterEvent(sender, ea);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginOrRegisterArgs ea = new LoginOrRegisterArgs("register");
        LoginOrRegisterEvent(sender, ea);
    }
}

public class LoginOrRegisterArgs
{
    public LoginOrRegisterArgs(string s) {Value = s;}
    public string Value {get; private set;}
}
```

**UserControl2**

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ControlFinishedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ControlFinishedHandler ControlFinshedEvent;
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string SetLogonType { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlFinshedEvent(sender, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

**UserControl3 & UserControl4** exactly the same except for different Class Name

```
public partial class UserControl3 : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ControlFinishedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ControlFinishedHandler ControlFinshedEvent;
    public UserControl3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlFinshedEvent(sender, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. This I've used your first solution and it works perfect, may you enjoy rivers of honey and dozens of virgins in thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, one of the best way I know to pass data between forms is to use events.

Basically, in the "child" forms, you declare an event that will be handled, or listened to, by the "main" form.

See the referenced answer from my comment, and if you have specific questions on how to adapt it, ask away.

Cheers